# How to display list items from database next to each other?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, dom

I have the following page, where a list of attractions from my "attraction" table are displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />



<title>VisitBulgaria</title>
</head>



<div class="banner">




<a href="home.html">
<img src="images/banner.png"   alt="kimtech" border="0" height="150" width="500" /></a>

<div class="namelog">


<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['ID'])){


 echo $Forename." ".$LastName; 
 echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a> &sol; '; 
 echo '<a href="userpage.html">Account</a>'; 

}

 else {

 if (!isset($_SESSION['ID'])){


 echo '<a href="login.php">Log In</a> &sol; ';
 echo '<a href="register.php">Register</a>';

 }
}
?>
</div>




</div>

<div class="center">
<div class="menu">


<ul>
<li ><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li class='active'><a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a>


<ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="historyv.html">Historical Villages</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="nature.html">Nature</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sr.html">Seaside Resorts </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="wr.html">Winter Resorts </a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="atimes.html">Ancient Times</a>
            </li>

        </ul>


</li>
<li><a href="traditions.html">Traditions</a></li>
<li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>






</ul>

</div>










<div class="center1">


<?php

if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db(')) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}

$sql    = "SELECT `AttractionID`,`Name`, `Location`, `Description`, `Airport`, `imglink`, `imglink2`   FROM `attractions` WHERE `Category`='HistV'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}




while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 echo "<a href='attraction.php?village=" . $row['AttractionID'] . "'>" .  "<br />" .
          $row['Name']  .
           "<br />" .

         "<img src='" . $row['imglink2'] . "' height='130' width='150'> 

       </a>";

}
mysql_free_result($result);

?>







</div>







</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Right now the items from my database are displayed as a list one under the other, as expacted. 
How can I maake it so that it displays two items from the list next to each other, and under them another two and so on? 
Is there any CSS I can use for that?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could use a table.

Comment: If I use a table I can't click on them, and I need to be able to click on them

Comment: Well, don't put the href attribute in the `<td>` itself, but right after it: `<td><a href="#"> your content </a></td>`. It's not semantically correct since `a` as inline element element is used as block level element, but generally works. You could make it a block element with CSS: `a {display:block;}`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you target the even lists using the css nth child property to target the odd lists add something like this to your css

```
ul.submenu {

}
ul.submenu li {

    display: inline;
    height: 50px;

    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
}

ul.submenu li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #F00;
    clear: left;
}
```

hope this works i have updated the fiddle here customise to you usage [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MLtNq/)